# How to create Google like word suggestion 

Tags: spell-checking, google-suggest

How do I make a word suggestion system in search engine like Google's "did you mean ... " ?

Preferably using the vector space model method. I have googled it but didn't find a solution.

Comment: Why would we e-mail you instead of using this site as intended and posting an answer here?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work also check out http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [the example](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) from Peter Norvig (Director of Research at Google).

Comment: He gave an overview of this at DevDays its very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) search engine [has "did you mean" support](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/08/09/didyoumean.html), and it's open source, so you can take the code and see how it works or reuse it in your project. Actually, it's probably worth using the entire engine instead of reinventing the wheel by creating a new search engine from scratch.