# How to find common typos of Strings in c#.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, methods

I'm looking for a way to find common mis-spelling of strings when entered by the keyboard.  For example, I would like "house" to return "hoise", "hpuse", "jouse", etc. because the misspelled characters are close to the correct ones on a QWERTY keyboard.

If i could get this to work with numbers only that would still be a big help.  Given "101", return "111", "11", "01", "10", etc.  It doesn't have to be perfect, just return some common typos.

Does anyone know of an existing method to accomplish this or perhaps a suggestion on how I might write one myself?

Comment: Don't fogret that *transopsitions* are also frequnetly encoutnered.

Comment: Absolutely true.  @Oded's answer incorporates deletion, trasnposition, insertion, and alteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm iteself is not that complicated - you need a good dictionary to compare against.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work) SO question for more details.

[Here](http://www.norvig.com/spell-correct.html) is the algorithm itself is 21 lines of python, and [here](http://www.codegrunt.co.uk/2010/07/08/C-Sharp-Norvig-Spelling-Corrector.html#norvigSpell) a C# implementation.

Comment: Wow, I guess I'm trying to fight way out of my weight-class here.  Can you give a simple call example?  Also, I don't see a "dictionary" as you mentioned.

Comment: @Marc - look at the source code: `File.ReadAllText("big.txt")` is where the dictionary ("big.txt") is loaded. The program itself is a command line app, so you can simply run it on the command line.

Comment: Ok, I see.  I was hoping to integrate the feature into my application, where user can select a job number and program will return possible misstypes for that number (which is actually just a string composed mostly of numbers, but may contain a letter at the end.).

Comment: Also, big.txt.  Is this simply a giant list of words (like in a dictionary)?  Does it need to be in a certain format (Comma separated, tab delimited, etc)?

Comment: @MAW74656 - I believe it is one word per line.

Comment: Wait a sec, could I just put possible job number permutations in the file?  For example, this year they can only be 10xxxx[FRT].  I bet I could find those permutations easily enough.  I don't even need a "words" dictionary.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Oded - One last question: What is a StrEnum and how can I use it?  I'm used to Lists, are they similiar?  Can I foreach it?

Comment: @MAW74656 - It is an alias to `IEnumerable<string>` - see line 5 in the C# code (`using StrEnum = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>;`).

Comment: Ahhh, got it.  I see that I can use foreach to iterate through the collection.

Answer (score 0):

SpellCheck.NET seems to be a good choice.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/spellcheckparser.aspx

Comment: The misspelled feature could be helpful.  I'll look at it more if there aren't any better recommendations.