# How to find irregular string in a database column with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, search, search-engine

I have a table named product  and I have a product in this table named "Nike shoes". Now when I write for example "niksho" or "nsh", return to me "Nike shoes " record.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing such an algorithm can be a big task, if I have to do such a thing I will first try to find some API to do that

You can start by looking at this post
[Accessing Google spelling/suggestion API via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238924/accessing-google-spelling-suggestion-api-via-c-sharp)

And if you have time you can always start writing yours that would be accustomed to your requirements