# Query for Searching Entered Text(keyword)

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to write a query for searching a string (keyword) in a database.

When a user enters some text like 'Clothes' then the query should search for the 'Clothes' keyword in the whole database `ProductName, ProductCode, SubCategoryName, etc` and also for near/similar text. So it should display all 'Clothes' related products, similar to Google search engine.

Also include spelling mistakes such as 'Clotts', ' Clooths' or 'Clothos' then it should display 'Clothes' related items.

If some clarification is needed, please leave a comment.

I'm using VS2010 C#, MySql 5.5 Database

Comment: I suggest you first start with simple exact matching, and then build on. We won't write all that code for you. It's a lot of code.

Comment: suggest any keyword please. Eg- "Like" matches pattern. but i need similar/near text also..?

Comment: Full-text searching could be what you want, which is available on MyIsam tables. Otherwise you even may want to use a specialized search tools such as solr or lucene.

Comment: Google has spent last decade and hundreds of engineers to get where they are now. You're not getting it from a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: @ Amadan : sorry for Misunderstand.. :)  basically most of all website use similar method to search a product. so that's where my point stands for.

Comment: You might find the answers to [this question about Google "did you mean" searches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work) useful.

Answer (score 3):

> When a user enters some text like 'Clothes' then the query should search for the 'Clothes' keyword in the whole database

```
SELECT f1,f2,f3 FROM table1 
WHERE match (f1,f2,f3) AGAINST ('$search_term' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Note that in MySQL full-text search requires MyISAM tables.
It also does not fix spelling errors.

> Also include spelling mistakes such as 'Clotts', ' Clooths' or 'Clothos' then it should display 'Clothes' related items.

You are looking for a algorithm that includes [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Some people have written UDF that you can install with MySQL (as a dll on Windows) that gives you this functionality:
See: http://samjlevy.com/2011/03/mysql-levenshtein-and-damerau-levenshtein-udfs/
The link even includes a howto on installation of the UDF's.