# Compare similarity algorithms

Tags: levenshtein-distance, similarity, euclidean-distance, jaro-winkler

I want to use string similarity functions to find corrupted data in my database.

I came upon several of them:

- Jaro,
- Jaro-Winkler,
- Levenshtein,
- Euclidean and
- Q-gram,

I wanted to know what is the difference between them and in what situations they work best?

Comment: I've never heard of "Q-gram". Any reference for it?

Comment: This is a case where a wiki-walk [is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) [honestly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) [most](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) [appropriate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-gram) to quickly and coherently answer your question. Consider also: using [Shannon entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_entropy) or [mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) as a heuristic. The comparison is by problem space and efficiency, which you can get from the description and body.

Comment: This is a non-trivial mathematical field for which books are written and extensive research is undertaken, worthy of discussion that would be difficult to fit into a single SO answer. Would it be possible for you to be more specific?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Expanding on my wiki-walk comment in the errata and [noting some of the ground-floor literature on the comparability of algorithms that apply to similar problem spaces,](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cburch/pgss97/slides/0715-compare.html) let's explore the applicability of these algorithms before we determine if they're numerically comparable.

From Wikipedia, [Jaro-Winkler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance):

> In computer science and statistics, the Jaro–Winkler distance
>   (Winkler, 1990) is a measure of similarity between two strings. It is
>   a variant of the Jaro distance metric (Jaro, 1989, 1995) and
>   mainly[citation needed] used in the area of record linkage (duplicate
>   detection). The higher the Jaro–Winkler distance for two strings is,
>   the more similar the strings are. The Jaro–Winkler distance metric is
>   designed and best suited for short strings such as person names. The
>   score is normalized such that 0 equates to no similarity and 1 is an
>   exact match.

[Levenshtein distance:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

> In information theory and computer science, the Levenshtein distance
>   is a string metric for measuring the amount of difference between two
>   sequences. The term edit distance is often used to refer specifically
>   to Levenshtein distance.
>
> The Levenshtein distance between two strings is defined as the minimum
>   number of edits needed to transform one string into the other, with
>   the allowable edit operations being insertion, deletion, or
>   substitution of a single character. It is named after Vladimir
>   Levenshtein, who considered this distance in 1965.

[Euclidean distance:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)

> In mathematics, the Euclidean distance or Euclidean metric is the
>   "ordinary" distance between two points that one would measure with a
>   ruler, and is given by the Pythagorean formula. By using this formula
>   as distance, Euclidean space (or even any inner product space) becomes
>   a metric space. The associated norm is called the Euclidean norm.
>   Older literature refers to the metric as Pythagorean metric.

And [Q- or n-gram encoding:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-gram)

> In the fields of computational linguistics and probability, an n-gram
>   is a contiguous sequence of n items from a given sequence of text or
>   speech. The items in question can be phonemes, syllables, letters,
>   words or base pairs according to the application. n-grams are
>   collected from a text or speech corpus.
>
> The two core
>   advantages of n-gram models (and algorithms that use
>   them) are relative simplicity and the ability to scale up – by simply
>   increasing n a model can be used to store more context with a
>   well-understood space–time tradeoff, enabling small experiments to
>   scale up very efficiently.

The trouble is these algorithms solve different problems that have different applicability within the space of all possible algorithms to solve the [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) problem, in your data or in grafting a usable [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29) thereof. In fact, not all of these are  even *metrics*, as some of them don't satisfy the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Instead of going out of your way to define a dubious scheme to detect data corruption, **do this properly: by using [checksums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) and [parity bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit) for your data.** Don't try to solve a much harder problem when a simpler solution will do.

Comment: If you're trying to verify whether a database has been corrupted, use checksums and parity bits.  If you're trying to figure out what data is corrupted, you need to identify what kinds of corruption you're trying to fix (record linkage, polluted data, missing data, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

String similarity helps in a lot of different ways. For example

- google's did you mean results are calculated using string similarity.
- string similarity is used to correct OCR errors.
- string similarity is used to correct keyboard entering errors.
- string similarity is used to find most matching sequence of two DNAs in bioinformatics.

But as one size does not fit all. Every string similarity algorithm is designed for a specific usage though most of them are similar. For example [Levenshtein_distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is about how many char you change to make two strings equal.

```
kitten → sitten
```

Here distance is 1 character change. You may give different weights to deletion, addition and substitution. For example OCR errors and keyboard errors give less weight for some changes. OCR ( some chars are very similar to others ), keyboard some chars are very near to each other. Bioinformatic string similarity  allows a lot of insertion.

Your second example of "[Jaro–Winkler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance)  distance metric is designed and best suited for short strings such as person names"

Therefore you should keep in your mind about your problem.

> I want to use string similarity functions to find corrupted data in my database.

How your data is corrupted? Is it a user error , similar to keyboard input error? Or is it similar to OCR errors? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Google's *did you mean* is not calculated using string similarity. It's calculated by tracking users mistype and re-attempt a moment later. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/307344/1720014)