# search box in vb.net using sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have already search box in my website but I need to allow the mistake spelling to search like this:
if one person write (pineapel) it means (pineapple). I want him to find the (pineapple) in the data base

any help?
thank you in advance

this code works to find word in sentence in table sqlserver:

```
SqlDataSourceArticles.SelectCommand = "SELECT [id], [articleid], [title], [description], [imageurl], [date], [type] FROM [articles] WHERE ([title] LIKE '%' + @title + '%') ORDER BY [imageurl] DESC"
```

Note: @title is the session from the text box to the search page result

Comment: You can do this much more neatly with a stored procedure. All you'd need to do is pass your search parameter.

Comment: Perhaps this question: [How does the Google “Did you mean?” Algorithm work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQL's SOUNDEX() function to finds words based on their sound, not spelling.

```
WHERE (SOUNDEX([title]) = SOUNDEX(@title))
```