# Google Like Search Mechanism

Tags: nlp, semantics, google-search

I want to do search mechanism similar to google using NLP(Natural Language Processing) in java. The algorithm should be able to give auto-suggestions , spellcheck , get the meaning out of the sentence and display top relevant results.
For Example , if I typed "laptop" relevant results to be shown ["laptop bags","laptop deals","laptop prices","laptop services" ,"laptop tablet"]

Is it possible to achieve with NLP and Semantics? It would be appreciable if you post any reference links or ideas to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Google "Did you mean?" Algorithm work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work)

Comment: Please do your research. Instead of just briefing your requirement consider expanding by explaining what tools you have considered for the task and how you would like to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

"Get the meaning out of a sentence" - that's really difficult task. I don't believe even google does that in their search engine;) When talking about searching getting the meaning of query is not that important...but it really depends on what do you mean by "get the meaning", anyway you always can buy yourself something like "Google Search Appliance" - its a private google search box.

All the other requirements are quite straightforward. I'm from java land soi'd suggest you to look at:

- Apache Lucene - if you are a developer, it's an indexer created around full text searches
- [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) It's full blown,fast scalable server build around lucene that can do most of what you are asking.
- [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) Another one, in terms of functionality equal to elastic IMHO.