# Regex misspellings

Tags: regex

I have a regex created from a list in a database to match names for types of buildings in a game. The problem is typos, sometimes those writing instructions for their team in the game will misspell a building name and obviously the regex will then not pick it up (i.e. spelling "University" and "Unversity").

Are there any suggestions on making a regex match misspellings of 1 or 2 letters?

The regex is dynamically generated and run on a local machine that's able to handle a lot more load so I have as a last resort to algorithmically create versions of each word with a letter missing and then another with letters added in.

I'm using PHP but I'd hope that any solution to this issue would not be PHP specific.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Allow me to introduce you to the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), a measure of the difference between strings as the number of transformations needed to convert one string to the other.

It's also [built into PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php).

So, I'd split the input file by non-word characters, and measure the distance between each word and your target list of buildings.  If the distance is below some threshold, assume it was a misspelling.

I think you'd have more luck matching this way than trying to craft regex's for each special case.

Comment: Combined with some custom code for checking for silly characters this works really well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Google's implementation of "did you mean" by looking at previous results might also help:

[How do you implement a "Did you mean"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424/how-do-you-implement-a-did-you-mean)

Answer (score 3):

> [What is Soundex() ?  – Teifion (28 mins ago)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392282/1165522)

A soundex is similar to the levenshtein function Triptych mentions.  It is a means of comparing strings.  See: https://www.php.net/soundex

You could also look at metaphone and similar_text.  I would have put this in a comment but I don't have enough rep yet to do that. :D

Answer (score 2):

Back in the days we sometimes used Soundex() for these problems.

Comment: I think there is a strict definition using some algorithm to represent how a word sound. Many databases have a SOUNDEX() function that implements it. But less strictly it can be any function. It's very fun to write them! =) Search this site for "soundex". It shows up now and then.

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck; the algorithms folks have done lots of work on **approximate matching of regular expressions**.  The oldest of these tools is probably [`agrep`](http://www.tgries.de/agrep/) originally developed at the University of Arizona and now available in a nice open-source version.  You simply **tell `agrep` how many mistakes you are willing to tolerate** and it matches from there.  It can also match **other blocks of text besides lines**.   The [link above](http://www.tgries.de/agrep/) has links to a newer, GPLed version of `agrep` and also a number of language-specific libraries for approximate matching of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill, but Peter Norvig of Google has written an [excellent article](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) on writing a spell checker in Python. It's definitely worth a read and might apply to your case.

At the end of the article, he's also listed contributed implementations of the algorithm in various other languages.