# Regex expression to catch variant of a word

Tags: regex

I am looking for simple way to use regex and catch variant of word with simplest format.
For example, the 5 variants of the word below.

hike
hhike
hiike
hikke
hikkee

Using something similar to the format below...

[`([a-zA-Z]){4,}`]

Thanks

Comment: You will need to better define what you mean by variant. Show some samples which would and should not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like `/h+i+k+e+/`?

Meaning:

- The literal `h` character repeated 1 to infinity times
- The literal `i` character repeated 1 to infinity times
- The literal `k` character repeated 1 to infinity times
- The literal `e` character repeated 1 to infinity times

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/yL4bN9)

If each character can maximum be there twice, you can use `/h{1,2}i{1,2}k{1,2}e{1,2}/` meaning "present 1 or 2 times".

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a soundex kind of problem I think:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/392236/514463

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot solve this generically (i.e. for any word) under standard regex syntax.

For a given word, as others have pointed out, it is trivial.