# Where can I learn more about the Google search "did you mean" algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, spell-checking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you implement a “Did you mean”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424/how-do-you-implement-a-did-you-mean)

I am writing an application where I require functionality similar to Google's "did you mean?" feature used by their search engine:

[image]

Is there source code available for such a thing or where can I find articles that would help me to build my own?

Comment: You could google for it, I suppose...

Comment: Is this from a former Cuil engineer?

Comment: how is google formed? how internet get serched?

Comment: Look at similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work/307456#307456

Answer (score 125):

You should check out Peter Norvigs article about implementing the spell checker in a few lines of python:
[How to Write a Spelling Corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) It also has links for implementations in other languages (i.e. C#)

Comment: Side fact: Peter Norvig is Director of Research at Google.

Comment: This answer should be marked as accepted. Norvig's algorithm solves OP's problem, is pretty awesome, *and* it comes from Google. :)

Answer (score 28):

I attended a seminar by a Google engineer a year and a half ago, where they talked about their approach to this. The presenter was saying that (at least part of) their algorithm has little intelligence at all; but rather, utilises the huge amounts of data they have access to. They determined that if someone searches for "Brittany Speares", clicks on nothing, and then does another search for "Britney Spears", and clicks on something, we can have a fair guess about what they were searching for, and can suggest that in future.

*Disclaimer:* This may have just been part of their algorithm

Comment: RE Disclaimer: I assume it was/is. It's a very safe way to go about it. I couldn't imagine anybody coming up with an algorithm that searches a database full of english words, then trying to determine whether or not the query is similar to existing data.

Answer (score 17):

Python has a module called [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html). It provides a functionality called `get_close_matches`. From the Python Documentation:

> `get_close_matches(word, possibilities[, n][, cutoff])`
>
> Return a list of the best "good
>   enough" matches.  *word* is a sequence
>   for which    close matches are desired
>   (typically a string), and
>   *possibilities* is a list of    sequences against which to match
>   *word* (typically a list of strings).
>
> Optional argument *n* (default
>   `3`) is the maximum number of close
>   matches to    return; *n* must be
>   greater than `0`.
>
> Optional argument *cutoff* (default
>   `0.6`) is a float in the range [0,
>   1].    Possibilities that don't score
>   at least that similar to *word* are
>   ignored.
>
> The best (no more than *n*) matches
>   among the possibilities are returned
>   in a    list, sorted by similarity
>   score, most similar first.

```
  >>> get_close_matches('appel', ['ape', 'apple', 'peach', 'puppy'])
  ['apple', 'ape']
  >>> import keyword
  >>> get_close_matches('wheel', keyword.kwlist)
  ['while']
  >>> get_close_matches('apple', keyword.kwlist)
  []
  >>> get_close_matches('accept', keyword.kwlist)
  ['except']
```

Could this library help you?

Answer (score 5):

You can use http://developer.yahoo.com/search/web/V1/spellingSuggestion.html which would give a similar functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out the source code for Xapian which provides this functionality, as do a lot of other search libraries. http://xapian.org/

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it serves your purpose but a String Edit distance Algorithm with a dictionary might suffice for a small Application.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look at this article on [google bombing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_bomb). It shows that it just suggests answers based off previously entered results.

Comment: Yes, I think it learns from what other people had corrected certain searches to. For instance if you search for 'hunrgy man dinner' and then click on nothing and change it to 'hungry man dinner', Google takes note of that next time it gets the first search. I'm sure they have more tricks than that, too, such as a traditional spellcheck in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the "did you mean ?" feature doesn't check the spelling. It only gives you another query based on the content parsed by google.

Comment: No, it guesses alternatives based on misspellings. If you search for "katie sachoff" it comes up with "Did you mean katee sackhoff?"

Comment: I recently read an article in which a Google employee expounded upon how they have the world's most advanced spellchecker, since it will take the context of a word into account in ways that few others do.

Comment: @Alex JL- And they're probably right.

Comment: @Alex JL, But it still doesn't check anything. Proposing an alternative with a common mistake, or a really similar but more common word isn't a spelling correction it's just guessing.

Comment: @Colin Not sure what you mean - isn't that what every spell checker does? Detect a mispelled word, and use heuristics to guess what you mean instead? I mean, I misspelled 'misspelled' and Firefox is suggesting misspelled, dispelled, respelled, etc. It's not like they're artificial intelligence or something. I agree with Google that theirs works very well.

Comment: @Alex JL, I mean that if "everybody" write a word the wrong way, google will find the wrong word more important that the good one. It's isn't based on spelling rules but on most common use.

Comment: @Alex JL, for example (in french) the word "Obtue" is a common mistake, the correct spelling is "Obtuse", but as the mistake is really common, Google won't say anything about this word. Or in english if you search for "alterior" instead of "ulterior" it's considered as okay because it's used frequently.

Answer (score 1):

A great chapter to this topic can be found in the openly available [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/spelling-correction-1.html).

Answer (score 1):

U could use ngram for the comparisment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram

Using python ngram module: http://packages.python.org/ngram/index.html

```
import ngram

G2 = ngram.NGram([  "iis7 configure ftp 7.5",
                    "ubunto configre 8.5",
                    "mac configure ftp"])

print "String", "\t", "Similarity"
for i in G2.search("iis7 configurftp 7.5", threshold=0.1):
    print i[0], "\t", i[1]
```

U get:

```
>>> 
String  Similarity
"iis7 configure ftp 7.5"    0.76
"mac configure ftp  0.24"
"ubunto configre 8.5"   0.19
```

Comment: An N-Gram index is the only sound solution I've seen among the answers, why is this tumbled down? Well... aside of Peter Norvig's. But N-Grams can do it quite good.

Comment: Thank u :) N-Grams are the prefered way at google... as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [Levenshtein-Automata](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata)