# Fuzzy matching API in a long list of queries

Tags: java, fuzzy-comparison

I have an application which lets people ask predefined queries. However, the list of such queries is too long. Hence, the current approach is to let users enter a word in the search box and then show them the likely matches from the list of queries. ( Very much like google's "Did you mean" feature.)

Is there an API in Java available for this? I should be able to supply the list of queries. The API should provide a fuzzy match capability, so that incorrect spellings do not matter. ( That is why an exact String matching algorithm is not sufficient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found these Java implementation of [Peter Norvig's spell correction algorithm](http://www.norvig.com/spell-correct.html). 
A bit dated, but good for getting started.

1. [Spelling Corrector](http://raelcunha.com/spell-correct.php)
2. [jSpellCorrect](http://developer.gauner.org/jspellcorrect/)

Answer (score 0):

The magic word here may be "[regular expression](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)" -- anything you can model as a finite state machine can be done with regular expressions.

Failing that, you might look into "[digital search trees](http://www.cs.pitt.edu/~zzl/CS1501/recitation6/1501rec6.htm)" or "[tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)".

Comment: Are there APIs available for building a Trie?

Comment: But tries are only useful if whatever you have typed is already spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the API's i can suggest are:

- [Patricia Trie](http://code.google.com/p/patricia-trie/)
- [Trie](http://code.google.com/p/trie/)

**Similar SO Questions:**

- [How Does Google "Did you mean" algorithm work ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work)
- [Where can I learn about google did you mean ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763640/where-can-i-learn-more-about-the-google-search-did-you-mean-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a probabilistic algorithm using Soundex or a derivative would work? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex