# How do I approximate "Did you mean?" without using Google?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, nlp, machine-learning

I am aware of the duplicates of this question:

- [How does the Google “Did you mean?” Algorithm work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work)
- [How do you implement a “Did you mean”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424/how-do-you-implement-a-did-you-mean)
- ... and many others.

These questions are interested in how the algorithm actually works. My question is more like: Let's assume Google did not exist or maybe this feature did not exist and we don't have user input. How does one go about implementing an approximate version of this algorithm?

**Why is this interesting?**

Ok. Try typing "[qualfy](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=qualfy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&fp=170344a196d61403)" into Google and it tells you:

> **Did you mean:** *qualify*

Fair enough. It uses Statistical Machine Learning on data collected from billions of users to do this. But now try typing this: "[Trytoreconnectyou](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Trytoreconnectyou)" into Google and it tells you:

> **Did you mean:** *Try To Reconnect You*

Now this is the more interesting part. How does Google determine this? Have a dictionary handy and guess the most probably words again using user input? And how does it differentiate between a misspelled word and a sentence?

Now considering that most programmers do not have access to input from billions of users, I am looking for the best approximate way to implement this algorithm and what resources are available (datasets, libraries etc.). Any suggestions?

Comment: @Benjamin: Can I also have a list of datasets that can be leveraged? I am not from this domain so any extra help will be a boon.

Comment: Did you read the answers to the links you posted? The second answer to the first link points to http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html which is pretty much exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Google "Did you mean?" Algorithm work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work)

Comment: The Norvig link is also in the 3rd-highest answer to your second link.

Comment: Did you noticed that http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Traytoreconnectyou does not work?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you implement a "Did you mean"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424/how-do-you-implement-a-did-you-mean).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have a dictionary of words (all the words that appear in the dictionary in the worst case, all the phrases that appear in the data in your system in the best case) and that you know the relative frequency of the various words, you should be able to reasonably guess at what the user meant via some combination of the [similarity of the word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) and the number of hits for the similar word.  The weights obviously require a bit of trial and error, but generally the user will be more interested in a popular result that is a bit linguistically further away from the string they entered than in a valid word that is linguistically closer but only has one or two hits in your system.

The second case should be a bit more straightforward.  You find all the valid words that begin the string ("T" is invalid, "Tr" is invalid, "Try" is a word, "Tryt" is not a word, etc.) and for each valid word, you repeat the algorithm for the remaining string.  This should be pretty quick assuming your dictionary is indexed.  If you find a result where you are able to decompose the long string into a set of valid words with no remaining characters, that's what you recommend.  Of course, if you're Google, you probably modify the algorithm to look for substrings that are reasonably close typos to actual words and you have some logic to handle cases where a string can be read multiple ways with a loose enough spellcheck (possibly using the number of results to break the tie).

Comment: I've been looking for a word-distance algorithm for *yonks*. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

From the horse's mouth:  [How to Write a Spelling Corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)

The interesting thing here is how you don't *need* a bunch of query logs to approximate the algorithm.  You can use a corpus of mostly-correct text (like a bunch of books from Project Gutenberg).

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be done using a `spellchecker` along with `N-grams`.

For `Trytoreconnectyou`, we first check with all 1-grams (all dictionary words) and find a closest match that's pretty terrible. So we try 2-grams (which can be built by removing spaces from phrases of length 2), and then 3-grams and so on. When we try a 4-gram, we find that there is a phrase that is at 0 distance from our search term. Since we can't do better than that, we return that answer as the suggestion.

I know this is very inefficient, but Peter Norvig's post [here](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) suggests clearly that Google uses spell correcters to generate it's suggestions. Since Google has massive paralellization capabilities, they can accomplish this task very quickly.

Comment: Google do it fast not because it brute force all combinations, but because it heuristic search which draw complexity to sub-liniar.

Answer (score 2):

Impressive tutroail one how its work you can found here http://alias-i.com/lingpipe-3.9.3/demos/tutorial/querySpellChecker/read-me.html.

In few word it is trade off of query modification(on character or word level) to increasing coverage in search documents. For example "aple" lead to 2mln documents, but "apple" lead to 60mln and modification is only one character, therefore it is obvious that you mean apple.

Answer (score 2):

Datasets/tools that might be useful:

- WordNet
- Corpora such as the [ukWaC corpus](http://wacky.sslmit.unibo.it/doku.php?id=corpora)

You can use WordNet as a simple dictionary of terms, and you can boost that with frequent terms extracted from a corpus.

You can use the Peter Norvig link mentioned before as a first attempt, but with a large dictionary, this won't be a good solution.

Instead, I suggest you use something like locality sensitive hashing (LSH). This is commonly used to detect duplicate documents, but it will work just as well for spelling correction. You will need a list of terms and strings of terms extracted from your data that you think people may search for - you'll have to choose a cut-off length for the strings. Alternatively if you have some data of what people actually search for, you could use that. For each string of terms you generate a vector (probably character bigrams or trigrams would do the trick) and store it in LSH.

Given any query, you can use an approximate nearest neighbour search on the LSH described by [Charikar](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.110.1930&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to find the closest neighbour out of your set of possible matches.

Note: links removed as I'm a new user - sorry.

Answer (score 1):

@Legend - Consider using one of the variations of the [Soundex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).  It has some known flaws, but it works decently well in most applications that need to approximate misspelled words.

---

Edit (2011-03-16):

I suddenly remembered another Soundex-like algorithm that I had run across a couple of years ago.  In [this Dr. Dobb's article](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401251?pgno=2), Lawrence Philips discusses improvements to his Metaphone algorithm, dubbed Double Metaphone.

You can find a Python implementation of this algorithm [here](http://www.atomodo.com/code/double-metaphone/metaphone.py/view), and more implementations on the same site [here](http://www.atomodo.com/code/double-metaphone).

Again, these algorithms won't be the same as what Google uses, but for English language words they should get you very close.  You can also check out the wikipedia page for [Phonetic Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm) for a list of other similar algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [How does the Google "Did you mean?" Algorithm work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work)

Comment: Thank You. I did link to this in my question. I am more interested in what resources I can leverage (except Google) to get this task done.

Comment: Oops -- I see that now. Apologies.