# Designing a System that would detect typos and suggestions

Tags: spell-checking, trie, system-design

This was asked in an interview.

I think the answer can be done by constructing a trie of all valid words and then suggestions can be made based on a possible valid path which was otherwise given as incorrect.

Say if user types apfle, and system would detect that after ap a possible valid path was app, which would then satisfy apple.

Is there any better solution than this? Perhaps the one implemented by spell checkers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

[How does the Google "Did you mean?" Algorithm work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work)

[How do I approximate "Did you mean?" without using Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265416/how-do-i-approximate-did-you-mean-without-using-google)

[How to write a spelling corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)

[Youtube Video: Search 101](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syKY8CrHkck#t=22m03s)

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, since this is an interview question and the expected answer should be quite short. I guess this is one of those open ended question where Interviewer was looking for design approach rather than whole answer.

Answer (score 0):

Within typical search engines you will find a lot of Analyzer stuff, which directs to the same underlying problem. A very popular Analyzer would be the n-gram Analyzer.

Perhaps this helps.