# How does google checks spelling mistakes?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you implement a “Did you mean”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424/how-do-you-implement-a-did-you-mean)
>   [How does the Google “Did you mean?” Algorithm work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work)

Google does spelling correction very fast & accurately, but how, I was unable to grasp their idea.
I tried to follow the research [paper](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/pubs/archive/36180.pdf) and also followed another [link](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html), but failed to understand.

Can anyone just give me a basic understanding of how Google does this without dictionary, using error & language models?

Or if can give me any other useful link.

Comment: Google aside, the traditional way of checking spelling without a dictionary has always been a bloom filter. Very fast, very small.

Comment: @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi:are you talking about this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter ??

Comment: Perhaps you should follow the Natural Language Processing course on Coursera to get some ideas on the algorithms involved: https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp

Comment: What makes you think Google doesn't use a dictionary? Both the links you posted involve dictionaries of one kind or another.

Comment: The keyword is: Statistical machine learning. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307291/how-does-the-google-did-you-mean-algorithm-work

Comment: @Matthew Strawbridge:from the word dictionary i mean to say that words are stored in database just as we do in sql

Comment: This has been asked dozens of times before.  See @kunukn's link or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424/how-do-you-implement-a-did-you-mean), or most of the pages in the "linked" sidebar of those pages.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft :ya thanks sir link is helpful.

Comment: Well google must be using some complex algorithm to return result according to page rank but basically result with minimum edit distance and with some modifications is returned . And for implemention trie data structure can be used . 

More will be revealed with someone's ans.