# Compare Strings proximity in Java

Tags: string, compare, proximity, text-analysis

After searching in Google and StackOverflow I couldn't find any resource talking about comparison of strings proximity in Java, I only find results about différence between == and equals...

Do one of you know any library allowing to compare the "proximity" between two strings and giving a percentage of proximity ?

**Example :**
*car* and *bar* are very close,
*chicken* and *dog* are very different

The idea is to be able to compare for example a city written by a user with the cities I have in my database to avoid duplicate data. For example if the user writes "NewYork", i could tell him "Do you mean "New-York" ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Google for "nlp word similarity"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but NLP is not for finding synonyms or close words analyzing the sense of the word ?
Description of Wordnet : "WordNet® is a large lexical database of English. Nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs are grouped into sets of cognitive synonyms (synsets)"

Actually, I only want to compare close strings by characters and not by sense. Any idea ?

Comment: I used the Levenshtein distance algorithm for people who find this topic. It's not the best I think but it fits my needs.
It is available in StringUtils.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/307291/628943 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/41424/628943 might be of interest here

Answer (score 0):

I've used SecondString MongeElkan algorithm, you could look at Lucene's algorithms as well.

[SecondString Link](http://secondstring.sourceforge.net/)