# Similar search results by SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

The scenario is that if any student want to ask question online and that question is already asked by anyone and answers are also available then sql query will automatically search for the results.

The problem is that question is same but asked or typed differently (means string is not matching). So, how to search those results of similar asked question in database by sql query?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stackoverflow also displays 'Relevant Questions' when you try to post a new question. You can check how it's done at [What is the SQL used to do a search similar to "Related Questions" on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937059/what-is-the-sql-used-to-do-a-search-similar-to-related-questions-on-stackoverf)