# How to implement a SIMPLE "You typed ACB, did you mean ABC?"

Tags: nlp, spell-checking

*I know this is not a straight up question, so if you need me to provide more information about the scope of it, let me know. There are a bunch of questions that address almost the same issue (they are linked here), but never the exact same one with the same kind of scope and objective - at least as far as I know.*

**Context:**

- I have a MP3 file with ID3 tags for
  artist name and song title.
- I have two tables Artists and Songs
- The ID3 tags might be slightly off (e.g. Mikaell Jacksonne)
- I'm using ASP.NET + C# and a MSSQL database

I need to synchronize the MP3s with the database. Meaning:

1. The user launches a script
2. The script browses through all the MP3s
3. The script says "*Is 'Mikaell Jacksonne' 'Michael Jackson' YES/NO*"
4. The user pick and we start over

Examples of what the system could find:

*In the database...*

```
SONGS = {"This is a great song title", "This is a song title"}
ARTISTS = {"Michael Jackson"}
```

*Outputs...*

```
"This is a grt song title" did you mean "This is a great song title" ?
"This is song title" did you mean "This is a song title" ?
"This si a song title"  did you mean "This is a song title" ?
"This si song a title"  did you mean "This is a song title" ?
"Jackson, Michael" did you mean "Michael Jackson" ?
"JacksonMichael" did you mean "Michael Jackson" ?
"Michael Jacksno" did you mean "Michael Jackson" ?
```

*etc.*

I read some documentation from this [/how-do-you-implement-a-did-you-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424/how-do-you-implement-a-did-you-mean) and this is not exactly what I need since I don't want to check an entire dictionary. I also can't really use a web service since it's depending a lot on what I already have in my database. If possible I'd also like to avoid dealing with [distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) and other [complicated things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262133601).

---

I could use the [google api](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html#1_3) (or something similar) to do this, meaning that the script will try spell checking and test it with the database, but I feel there could be a better solution since my database might end up being really specific with weird songs and artists, making spell checking useless.

I could also try something like what has been explained [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240/similar-posts-like-functionality-using-ms-sql-server), using [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) [for c#](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive394.html).

Using a regular spell checker won't work because I won't be using words but names and 'titles'.

---

So my question is: is there a *relatively* simple way of doing this, and if so, what is it?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for a simple answer to a complicated problem. Given the constraints you've listed, I doubt you'll find an answer.

Comment: I doubt too, but who knows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a similarity factor.  Essentially, you want to compare your inputs ("Micheal Jackson", for example) to your expected values ("Michael Jackson"); if you score a very high similarity value to one of your expected values, you can ask the user.

One way of doing this is to hash the expected values into a fully packed hashtable.  If you get your hashing algorithm right (and yes, this is the tricky bit), each input will hash to the closest expected value; once you've found the closest expected value, you can run a similarity evaluation against the input and that expected value; if you're above a certain threshold, ask the user.

Comment: I didn't think of the hash, but that's true and very clever! Do you have pointers on where to look for such an hash algorithm?

Comment: @marcgg: You might try google for such a hash algorithm; however, you may need to do a lot of customization of it for your expected data set.  I don't know of any good references for such a thing off the top of my head...

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple but relatively inaccurate system would be to compare the characters of the strings, and measure the number of characters that are different/missing/added in the user's string.  If the number of characters is few enough (you might try weighting the differences based on key distance [lookup table] or somesuch), then ask the user if they meant a specific given string

Comment: this could work as a last resort. Meaning I try to lookup exact match, then something else maybe more accurate and then this. I'm sure there will be something like 30% of match, maybe less, but that's still an interesting idea, thanks!

Comment: The biggest hangup here is going to be how you compare the characters, since "ABCDE" should only be one character away from "ACDE", not 4 characters away as one old attempt of mine gave (can you figure out why?)

Comment: It was doing that because you were testing the exact position of letters. I guess doing a mix like "same letter-same position: +10, same letter-different position: +1" could give something a bit more robust. Or not.

Comment: Yep, I wasn't checking to see if a letter had been added or removed when I ran through the string.  Of course, you can't really tell how many letter the user might be off by.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-trivial task. Check out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) for more info about algorithms that deal with this. You hit on soundex already, but there are other transformations that you're looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very similar to creating a spell checker, which is best done with a [ternary search tree](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2001/jw-0216-ternary.html).  The link uses Java for it's example, but the data structure is the important part. The data structure behaves like a Hash with the properties that were mentioned by McWafflestix.